# Modify SharePoint site title and description via web services?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, service, web

I am using SharePoint 2010 and would like to know if it is possible to modify the title and description of an existing site using one of the exposed web services of SharePoint.

Can anyone point me to the right .asmx service and method as I am unable to find a suitable one? If this does not exist what is the alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no web service to handle that input... you could however write your own web service and update the site title/description using SPWeb title as found here:

http://www.uccorner.com/227/sharepoint/updating-site-title-spweb-web-title-programmatically/

Thanks!
Kyle